# trouble installing gcc 4.8.1

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gcc

I installed gcc as described below.

it installed pretty well, but when I call `gcc -v` it just shows the former version `gcc4.6.3`. I do not know where to find the installation so that I can make a link to call it.

```
tar xzf gcc-4.6.2.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.6.2
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.6.2/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.6.2 
make
make install
```

All were done from my home directory.

Comment: It appears based on your question that you have attempted to install 4.6.2, not 4.8.1 as in your title. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `gcc-4.8` with:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8
```

No difficult compilation methods are needed to be employed.